# Efficient way to generate all possibilities of string from characters

Tags: python, iterable, dna-sequence

I am trying to randomly generate a string of n length from 5 characters (`'ATGC '`). I am currently using `itertools.product`, but it is incredibly slow. I switched to `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`, but it skips some values. Is there a faster way of doing this? For my application order does matter.

```
for error in itertools.product('ATGC ', repeat=len(errorPos)):
    print(error)
    for ps in error:
        for pos in errorPos:
            if ps == " ":
                fseqL[pos] = ""
            else:
                fseqL[pos] = ps
```

Comment: What are the inner loops for?

Comment: I am using this algorithm to error correct a DNA strand. Those inner loops are for inserting the result from the interable into the strand.

Comment: If I reversed the results from `itertools.combinations` and used those, would that give me all the possibilities?

Comment: Can't you use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27552377/8508004) and just give it a sequence of Ns of the length you need? (Came from [Biostars post 'all posible sequences from consensus'](https://www.biostars.org/p/282490/).)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a random single sequence:

```py
import random
def generate_DNA(N):
    possible_bases ='ACGT'
    return ''.join(random.choice(possible_bases) for i in range(N))
one_hundred_bp_sequence = generate_DNA(100)
```

That was posted before post clarified spaces need; you can change possible_sequences to include a space if you need spaces allowed.

---

If you want all combinations that allow a space, too, a solution adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27552377/8508004), which I learned of from [Biostars post 'all possible sequences from consensus'](https://www.biostars.org/p/282490/):

```py
from itertools import product

def all_possibilities_w_space(seq):
   """return list of all possible sequences given a completely ambiguous DNA input. Allow spaces"""
   d = {"N":"ACGT "}
   return  list(map("".join, product(*map(d.get, seq)))) 
all_possibilities_w_space("N"*2) # example of length two
```

The idea being N can be any of "ACGT " and the multiple specifies the length. The `map` should specify C is used to make it faster according to [the answer I adapted it from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27552377/8508004).